# What CSS properties do I need to specify in order for certain elements to be hidden behind the HTML body?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I am building a game in React that spawns new letter components (a small circular div with a random letter displayed) every X-number of seconds. The newly generated components are animated to give the impression of 'falling' from the top of the screen, and they live inside of a content box, as rows and columns.

Simple example:

```
<body>
  <content-box>
    <letters>
    </letters>
  </content-box>
</body>
```

The content box overlaps the HTML body, and the letters overlap the content box, as they should. However, I would like for the newly generated letters to appear as if they are falling from somewhere beyond the top of my content box, if that makes sense, by hiding the letters from view until they are within the range of the content-box. I assumed that a z-index would do the trick, though upon writing one, I realized that it didn't quit make sense. Is what I'm trying to accomplish here possible?

Example of current CSS:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500
}
content-box {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 900
}
letters {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 700 // ??? Should overlap content-box but 'under-lap' body
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use the [`overflow: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow?retiredLocale=de) property on your `content-box`, which hides children and any other content, if it is "outside" of it. Does this help you?

Comment: @philale Brilliant, it does indeed!! Thank you very much.